# Merging components of DateTime fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I've got two attributes `start_time` and `end_time`.

How can I use the date (excluding the time) that was entered for the `start_time` to be included into the `end_time` field (as the start+end times will occur on the same day, so there is no point prompting the user to enter it twice).

View:

```
<div class="day">
    <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :start_time, "Date"  %>
       <%= f.date_select :start_time,:default => Time.now+1.week, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :ampm => true %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :start_time, "Start Time" %>
        <%= f.time_select :start_time, :ignore_date => true, :minute_step => 15, :ampm => true, :default => Time.now.beginning_of_day + 9.hours %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :end_time, "End Time" %>
        <%= f.time_select :end_time, :minute_step => 15, :ampm => true, :default => Time.now.beginning_of_day + 15.hours %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to_function "Remove this day", "remove_fields(this)" %>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a neat way to do this.  You will have to extract the individual components:

```
t1 = start_time
t2 = end_time
t2 = Time.local(t1.year,t1.month,t1.day,t2.hour,t2.min,t2.sec).in_time_zone
```

Be aware of which time zone you are working in.  You may need to use `Time.utc` instead of `Time.local`.